# Processing an array of data with a pattern in it in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, split

So I've got this String with book information:

```
String data = "Harry Potter 1 | J.K. Rowling| 350 | Fantasy | Hunger Games | Suzanne Collins | 500 | Fantasy | The KingKiller Chronicles | Patrick Rothfuss | 400 | Heroic Fantasy"
```

Then I split the String:

```
String splitData = data.split("\\|");
```

This will cause Harry Potter 1 to be in position 0, J.K. Rowling to be in position 1, 350 to be in position 2, etc.

You might see a pattern in here, which is the fact that at position 0 is a title of a book, at position 1 is the author, at position 2 is the amount of pages and at position 3 is the genre. Then it starts again at position 4, which is again the title of a book, position 5 being the Author of the book, etc etc. I assume that you understand where I'm going.

Now let's say that I want to display all those elements separately, like printing all the titles apart, all the authors, all the amount of pages, etc. How would I accomplish this?

This should be possible to do since the titles are in 0, 4, 8. The authors are in 1, 5, 9, etc.

Comment: Nope, if you look at my previous question, I'm trying to make a manga reader. This gets the title of the manga, the author, etc, etc. I'm trying to process this but I don't know how ^^.

Comment: try on your own first, if some problem occurs, then ask.

Comment: What have you tried? You already figured out the relation between array indexes and "types", you have all you need.

Comment: You have the pattern down, (titles in 0,4,8 ect.) Your pretty much done!

Comment: Yeah, just a bad day today, but I got the answer I needed already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String data = "Harry Potter 1 | J.K. Rowling| 350 | Fantasy | Hunger Games | Suzanne Collins | 500 | Fantasy | The KingKiller Chronicles | Patrick Rothfuss | 400 | Heroic Fantasy"; 
    String[] splitData = data.split("\\|");
    for(int i=0; i<splitData.length;i++) {
        if(i % 4 == 0) System.out.println("Title: "+splitData[i]);
        else if(i % 4 == 1) System.out.println("Author: "+splitData[i]);
        else if(i % 4 == 2) System.out.println("Pages: "+splitData[i]);
        else if(i % 4 == 3) System.out.println("Genre: "+splitData[i]);
    }
```

Difficult, isnt it?

Comment: I swear to [name of spiritual leader you believe in] that I would have known this any other day, but I'm having many troublesome thoughts today so my mind was clogged. Thanks though! Btw, 3 of those if-statements should be else-if statements... that makes the program slightly more efficient.

Comment: you can also use switch: i % 4 will be calculated only once

Answer (score 2):

You can recall that `for` loop lets you perform *any* modifications in the last expression, not only `i++`. For this case, you can use `i += 4`. Then in each iteration the name will ne at `splitData[i]`, the author at `splitData[i+1]`, the number of pages at `splitData[i+2]`, and the genre at `splitData[i+3]`.